# EF 6.1 Sequence Contains more then one element

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I Updated my EF from 5 to 6 today , I followed following steps from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx

The problem now is, when I query against any repository, such as like this:

```
mapEntitiesContext.ContextParameterScreens
                  .Where(p => p.OwningTenantId == IdentityHelper.IdPrv.TenantId)
                  .Select(p => new
                               {
                                   p.ParameterScreenDefinitionId,
                                   p.MedicalContextId
                               })
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the error:

> Sequence contains more then one element.

I never had this issue with EF 5.0.

```
Stacktrace

    System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Result StackTrace:  

   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass281.<IndexesEqual>b__27e(String c)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual[TSource](IEnumerable`1 first, IEnumerable`1 second, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.IndexesEqual(ConsolidatedIndex consolidatedIndex1, ConsolidatedIndex consolidatedIndex2, ICollection`1 renamedColumns)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass272.<FindAddedIndexes>b__26e(ConsolidatedIndex i1, ConsolidatedIndex i2)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DynamicEqualityComparer`1.Equals(T x, T y)
   at System.Linq.Set`1.Find(TElement value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Set`1.Add(TElement value)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ExceptIterator>d__99`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ModelMatches(VersionedModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

Comment: Every query :) For Example: mapEntitiesContext.ContextParameterScreens.Where(p => p.OwningTenantId == IdentityHelper.IdPrv.TenantId).
                Select(p => new { p.ParameterScreenDefinitionId, p.MedicalContextId }).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: you can accept your own answer.Please do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After alot of testing and debugging I finally found a 'solution'.

I started with a new project and started with 'add-migration InitialCreate -verbose', and with EF 6.0, this method creates a new file with the name: 'InitialSchema'.

When I started with my current migrations (more than a year ago), the initial file was named: Initial.
Just adding an empty class with name 'InitialSchema' fixed my error.

```
public partial class InitialSchema : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

When I started my application and created my DbContext, EF was crashing on this

Hope it helps other people too :)

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace you posted indicates that it's not a problem with your query, but with the underlying Entity Framework infrastructure. It tries to initialize the database before doing anything with it (ie. your query), and as a part of doing so compares its existing schema with the current one. It fails when comparing indexes for some table you added or removed columns from since the last time you ran EF on the database - the `SingleOrDefault` that throws is in `IndexesEqual` method of [`EdmModelDiffer`](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Infrastructure/EdmModelDiffer.cs). So you can:

- recreate the database if it's your development database - just drop it and EF will recreate it the way it wants,
- disable automatic database initialization in EF (the way to do so differs by version) so that it doesn't choke on your model,
- figure out why it fails with your model (at the moment you know that it expects a single column to have a certain name but there is more than one) and work around it.

Comment: Tried recreating database. Unfortunately, the error persists. I use manual migrations.